# How to change position to fixed without "jumping"

Tags: jquery

I im trying to set the position to fixed on scoll. I need it to happen without the div underneath has a position.

I created this fiddle of how i would like it to be, but without the div #body is positioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/mortenhauberg/fPTnq/embedded/result/

Is it posible?

I am new to javascript/jQuery!

I hope you understand my poor english!

Morten Hauberg

Comment: Your demo is working fine. Not sure what you want it to do which it's not currently doing.

Comment: I am bad at explaining :)

I want the div #sub_menu to scroll down as it do when the page is loaded. When you scroll it slides down over the #body.

Comment: Isn't that what it's doing already?  Your menu is sliding over the body as you scroll down.

Comment: I want it to slide in between the #body, so that the #body moves down the page. Also when you have scrolled.

Sorry about the poor explanation!

Comment: I think you're trying to avoid the menu pushing the body down.  Check my answer below and see if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: No, i am trying to do the opposite :)

Comment: As it stands, it's working fine based on your jsfiddle link.  The only thing I can see, is that you're aiming at a particular browser, or possibly browser version (IE is known for random bugs between versions)

Comment: I am using safari and fire fox.

When the page is loaded and before you scroll it works as i should do. But when you scroll the #sub_menu slides down over til #body.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean.  If you scroll the browser viewport, it collapses the body to the header, so when you click the menu, it scrolls over the body. You should've added that we need to scroll the browser viewport for this 'bug' to happen ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, the class `not_fixed` is applying a `position:absolute` when the menu is within the scrollable area.  But when the user scrolls the browser viewport outside the viewable area, you have script adding a css class to the `<div id="menu">`.  Is adds `fixed` class (which applies a `position:fixed`).  Remove the `not_fixed` class, and it will stop breaking the scroll.

```
<div id="menu" class="not_fixed">
   <h1 id="show">MENU</h1>           
   <div class="hide" id="sub_menu" style="display: none;">
      TEKST<br>
      TEKST<br>
      TEKST<br>
      TEKST<br>
      TEKST<br>
      TEKST<br>
      TEKST<br>
   </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Now the #sub_menu slides down over the #body all the time. I want it to slide down and "push" the #body down the site.

Comment: ok, that's what your example is doing, as the others have said.  I don't see any problems with your current example.

Comment: When you scroll down the positioning changes, as i should do, but then the #sub_menu slides down over the #body

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, your fiddle appears to be doing what you are asking for.  In your comments above it sounds like you might be having trouble with the content below the target element when it goes fixed.  A common problem is that the content below jumps under the target when it goes fixed.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates a header that goes fixed after some scrolling, and the content below it does not jump up the page.  Also, this demo shows that you can set the header to "unfix" further down the page so it will not go over your footer.

Here is the usage from the demo:

```
// the limit is optional, but it will make the header move up the
// page again once it reaches the 7th paragraph
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header').scrollToFixed( { limit: $($('h2')[7]).offset().top } );
});
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/2/

Here is the jquery plugin and its source: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed